# Get next element of $(this).val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I get the next element in html using javascript?

I have three

```
 <input type="number"  class="number" >
```

in html and a script like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var limite = <?php echo str_replace('"', '&quot;', trim($row["tot_costi_fissi_struttura"])) ?>;
var somma;
var val;

$(".number").change(function(){
val = parseFloat($(this).val());

somma = 0;
$(".number").each(function(){
somma += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
var resto = limite - somma > 0 ? limite - somma : 0;
$("#limite").html(resto);
if(somma > limite){
var diff = somma - limite;
$(this).val(val - diff);
}


})
});
```

I need to get not only the current element, but also the next one.

I've tried this:

```
valnext = parseFloat($(this).next().val());
```

but it doesn't work

Thanks in advance

Comment: PLEASE NEVER mix HTML, PHP and Javascript in one file ^^

Comment: They need to be siblings for that to work -- is there anything wrapping each of the inputs so that they are "cousins" instead of siblings?

Comment: provide your HTML code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the items are at arbitrary locations in DOM then you can use [`jQuery.index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/). Assume that we have three `.number` items and second one is changed, then:

```
var $this = $(this),             // this element
    $that = $(".number"),        // group of element to which this element belongs
    index = $that.index($this),  // index of this in that group
    $next = $that.eq(index + 1); // next element in that group
                                 // note that .eq silently returns empty jquery
                                 // object if out of bounds index is specified
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/N6DgW/)

Comment: just asking curiously.. why not `$(this).next()` ?

Comment: @Mr_Green: OP mentioned that `$(this).next()` is not working so most likely they are not siblings.

Comment: @SalmanA Thanks for suggestion... in my code  I've add yout lines and at the end of my script instead of doing $(this).val(val - diff); I've write $(next).val(val - diff); But nottin' happens

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the type, to get a text type use:

```
$(this).next().text();
```